# How do I retrieve the status and the congestion on a network?

Tags: blockchain

So basically I have an assignment that requires me to make a web app that can get the status (up or down) and the congestion(load) on etherium mainnet, solano and bitcoin lightning networks.
I am unable to figure out on how to go with this.
I don't think that distributed networks like such even go down, except maybe in the case of solano. Also, congestion isn't a metric so I need to define something appropriate and use some API which gets the required details for me. Please suggest some free APIs for this.
Also, congestion isn't making sense on bitcoin lightning network.
Can someone please guide me in the correct direction on how to start this assignment?

Answer (score 0):

These blockchains generate blocks at a fixed rate. So you could make a statistics when the next block will arrive. As you said the blockchains will run if at least one node is mining blocks, so you can't measure downtime, but you could measure if a blocks takes too long to be produced. The end result is similar people won't see new transactions.

For the load you could check how many pending transactions are in the pending pool. A more congested network will have a lot of pending transactions. Another measure is how full are the blocks mined.